# Most eficient way to change dtype of all numeric columns in a pandas DataFrame? (when categorical columns are also present)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance, dtype

I have a pandas DataFrame with a mix of categorical and numeric columns. A simplified version of the DataFrame is as follows:

```
epi = pd.DataFrame({"Hospital": ["10702", "10835", "14303", "14303"],
                    "Service": ["Dermatology", "Dermatology", "Dermatology", "Rheumatology"],
                    "Product": ["X1", "X1", "X2", "X5"],
                    "202112": [20, 32, 54, 12],
                    "202201": [99, 0, 12, 14],
                    "202202": [102, 12, 43, 12]
                   })
```

I need to convert all the numeric columns of this DataFrame (202112, 202201, 202202) to the dtype `"float64"` (for reasons that are not relevant here).

Since I have some categorical columns that complicate things, and the database is large and quite computationally demanding, **¿What is the best way in terms of efficiency to select just numeric columns and change their dtypes to "float64"?**

I came across with the following solution. But not sure if it is the most efficient nor the most pythonic way to do it:

```
cols = epi.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
epi[cols] = epi[cols].astype("float64")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a good solution. Another approach might be to [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) (the operation is in place):

```
epi.update(epi.select_dtypes(include=np.number).astype('float64'))
```

Output:

```
  Hospital       Service Product  202112  202201  202202
0    10702   Dermatology      X1    20.0    99.0   102.0
1    10835   Dermatology      X1    32.0     0.0    12.0
2    14303   Dermatology      X2    54.0    12.0    43.0
3    14303  Rheumatology      X5    12.0    14.0    12.0
```

dtypes:

```
Hospital     object
Service      object
Product      object
202112      float64
202201      float64
202202      float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `astype` with a dict:

```
epi = epi.astype({col: np.float64 for col in epi.columns
                     if np.issubdtype(epi[col].dtype, np.number)})
```

Output:

```
>>> epi
  Hospital       Service Product  202112  202201  202202
0    10702   Dermatology      X1    20.0    99.0   102.0
1    10835   Dermatology      X1    32.0     0.0    12.0
2    14303   Dermatology      X2    54.0    12.0    43.0
3    14303  Rheumatology      X5    12.0    14.0    12.0

>>> epi.dtypes
Hospital     object
Service      object
Product      object
202112      float64
202201      float64
202202      float64
dtype: object
```